Guidance on Designing Mechanical Models for O-Ring Sealing? Recommendations for Handbooks?
I’m working on a mechanical design that involves O-ring sealing. I have a couple of questions and would greatly appreciate any advice:

Mechanical Design for O-Ring Sealing: What are the key considerations when modeling for effective O-ring sealing? Are there specific guidelines for dimensions, compression ratios, or tolerances to achieve a reliable seal?

Material Selection and Pressure Handling: Is there a comprehensive handbook or resource that explains how to choose the appropriate O-ring material based on pressure, temperature, and other environmental factors? I’m particularly interested in understanding the pressure percentages and how different materials behave under these conditions.


Any recommendations for handbooks, online resources, or software that can help with these aspects would be fantastic!
Thanks in advance for your insights!

VTC, see https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
